# Integer array of variable length

Tags: c

I have a

```
int val,i;
scanf("%d",&val);
int a[] = { (val & 0x7) , (val & 0x5) };
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
printf("%d\n",a[i]);
```

I am confused whether the above code is good or not?
I get this error on some compiler

```
expression must have a constant value
```

but on another this works fine.So is this code good?

Comment: On which compiler it does not work?

Comment: How many elements does `a` have? If you need two, why not to define `int a[2]`?

Comment: @a3mlord This is just an example I need something like this

Comment: @a3mlord; You need an update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables in initializer list is not allowed before C99.

#### C89: 6.5.7:

> All the expression in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration or in an initializer list for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be constant expressions.

From C99, it is allowed. Make sure you are compiling with `-std=c99` flag.